# What's the difference between print and head?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I know `head` gives you the beginning section of a file. But in this case, I'm trying to go through my source control and find every file that has a shebang line. And I'm failing to get results when I use `head`.  What am I doing wrong?

When I say doesn't work, i mean it returns nothing. But I know it should've returned something.

**Works, but slow!**

```
find . | awk '!/((\.jpeg)|(\.jpg)|(\.html)|(\.png))$/ {print $0; }' | xargs grep "#!"
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
find . | awk '!/((\.jpeg)|(\.jpg)|(\.html)|(\.png))$/ {head $0; }' | xargs grep "#!"
```

**Update**
As @devnull pointed out, and easily verified by googling. I'll list here for reference: 
[Awk Commands](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-13)

```
if ( conditional ) statement [ else statement ]
while ( conditional ) statement
for ( expression ; conditional ; expression ) statement
for ( variable in array ) statement
break
continue
{ [ statement ] ...}
variable=expression
print [ expression-list ] [ > expression ]
printf format [ , expression-list ] [ > expression ]
next
exit
```

Comment: @manatwork : Yeah, bang on.  I don't use `awk` much but it just occurred to me that `print` is internal.  Throw up an answer if you're sure.

Comment: `head` isn't an `awk` command.

Comment: Me thinks devnull summed this up.

Comment: @devnull Thanks - I never realized that `awk` has a specific, and very limited set of commands... _shame on me_ I'll have to add it to my reading list.

Comment: Note that along with the list above, awk also has builtin functions - here is a list for gawk (GNU awk) https://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/gawk/gawk_13.html. Among them is the `system` function which can be used to run arbitrary programs/commands, although generally there are better solutions than to use this.

Answer (score 3):

Awk is a command which is an interpreter for a programming language that is aimed at simple text processing. Though it can, it's not really meant to be used to call other commands like the `head` command.

Here, you could have a shell do the work:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.png' \
                  -o -name '*.html' \) -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    IFS= read -r line < "$file" &&
       case $line in
         ("#!"*) printf "%s\n" "$file: $line"
       esac
  done' sh {} +
```

If you wanted to do it with `awk`, with GNU `awk`:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.png' \
                  -o -name '*.html' \) -exec awk '
    /^#!/ {print FILENAME ": " $0}; {nextfile}' {} +
```

With other `awk`s:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.png' \
                  -o -name '*.html' \) -exec awk '
   BEGIN {
     for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
       if ((getline < ARGV[i]) > 0 && /^#!/)
         print ARGV[i] ": " $0
     exit
   }' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `grep -R '^#!' .` should rapidly give a list of candidates for more detailed analysis.